# Tensorboard: "localhost refused to connect", Tensorboard page completely blank

Tags: python-3.x, windows, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I can't get TensorBoard to show anything but a blank page (not even a header or anything) when loading "localhost:6006" in my Chrome in Windows. The only thing indicating that tensorboard is indeed running on this port is the tab title.
I mostly followed the official tutorial from tensorflow, but implemented it in my own project: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/get_started

Inside the Jupyter Notebook I get a gray field saying: "localhost refused to connect" (it's in german on my computer, but it should translate somehow like this.)
There are logs in the specified directory already, but I don't think that's even relevant to my problem.
I have seen tons of quite similar questions out in the internet, but they all seemed to be somehow different and none of the solutions worked for me.

I tried writing 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost with no luck.
I killed the "tensorboard.exe" process and deleted all the files in "...\temp.tensorboard-info", still nothing.
Restarted my machine, still no luck.

I used the following lines of code concerning tensorboard:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
...
logdir = os.path.join("logs", datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S"))
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(logdir, histogram_freq=1)
...
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), epochs=20, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])

%tensorboard --logdir=./logs --host localhost
```

I never managed to see anything of the actual Tensorboard GUI. I see the "tensorboard.exe" process running in the task manager.

Comment: Whoever faces the same problem may find a solution here:
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60983776/tensorboard-not-running-properly-on-port-6006/62423241#62423241

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by reinstalling my whole Anaconda/python environment. The problem was probably caused by multiple installations of tensorflow or some damaged installation.
I hope this helps people with the similar problem.