# Tensorboard Not Running Properly on port 6006

Tags: tensorboard

I've been having problems with tensorboard probably due to a unclean exit in windows10. I use the below code to launch it in Jupyter:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir={dir}
```

this is what I got:

```
'ERROR: Timed out waiting for TensorBoard to start. It may still be running as pid 24472.'
```

and below code in cmd window to launch TB in Chrome:

```
$ tensorboard --logdir {dir}'
```

this is what I got:
[tensorboard_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiuAo.png)

I've done some research and tried the following things:

1. `-"taskkill /im tensorboard.exe /f"` to kill all live pids in
   command
2. -deleted all the pid-xxxx.info files in the "%TMP%.tensorboard-info" directory.
3. -deleted the whole "%TMP%.tensorboard-info" directly

That didn't help.

Then I tried to change the port to `6005` by adding `"--port 6005"` in command window and TB could launch in Chrome under "`localhost:6005`. but it won't work in Jupyter.

Any idea how I can get TB to run in Jupyter again? Thanks.

Comment: Potentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59503668

Answer (score 4):

Reading this [Github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2481), you can find that specifying the host manually when launching Tensorboard apparently does the trick.

Instead of

```
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}
```

Run

```
%tensorboard --logdir {logs_base_dir}  --host localhost
```

Answer (score -2):

Did you try mentioning the same port in the Jupyter notebook

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir={dir} --port=6005
```

Comment: Yes, I did. """ERROR: Timed out waiting for TensorBoard to start. It may still be running as pid 101780.""", And it diables my Chrome TensorBoard, it will displace("""No scalar data was found.""")

Comment: When asking for information, please use comments instead of answer. I have the same problem BTW